# Generic type of a Class's instance

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a `Map` of "services" on TypeScript. Those services are classes. Like so:

```js
    export class MyService {
      constructor() {
        // do something
      }

      someMethod() {}      
    }
```

Witch is pretty simple in theory. Except that i can't figure how to "store" those service once they are instantiated in my `Map` that you can find here:

```js
    const servicesMap = new Map<string, unknown>();

    export interface Service extends Object {
      prototype: {
        constructor: { name: string };
      };
    }

    /**
     * Return an instantiated service from the serviceMap
     *
     * @param service
     */
    export function getService<T>(service: Service): T {
      if (!servicesMap.has(service.constructor.name)) {
        throw new Error(`error_services: ${service.constructor.name} is not registered`);
      }

      return servicesMap.get(service.constructor.name) as T;
    }

    /**
     * Save an instantiated service in the serviceMap
     *
     * @param service
     */
    export function registerService<T>(service: Service) {
      if (servicesMap.has(service.constructor.name)) {
        throw new Error(
          `error_services: ${service.constructor.name} has already been registered and should be register only in services-provider.ts`
        );
      }

      servicesMap.set(service.constructor.name, service as T);
    }
```

I cannot manage to find a valid type to use for `interface Service`

Comment: Use a shared (maybe abstract) parent class?

Comment: @zenly I might miss something but it's not fitting my need since i'm trying to use a native property of the instantiated class as a key for the `Map`